# Mathematica heat transfer tutorial problem

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, heat-equation

I want to solve some heat transfer problems with Mathematica. I am trying to run the [heat transfer tutorial cases](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html#803398496) but I am always getting the error "NDSolveValue: Equation or list of equations expected instead of ..."
I was reading into the HeatTransferPDEComponent documentation and tried running the [example case](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeatTransferPDEComponent.html), but the same problem appears. See the code below, I tried some stuff I found on the forum in the top 3 lines.

What is causing these errors and how can I fix it?

[image: picture of code with error]

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Clear[vars, pars, \[CapitalOmega], eqn, Tfun]

ClearAll[vars, pars, \[CapitalOmega], eqn, Tfun]

vars = {\[CapitalTheta][x], {x}};

pars = <|"ThermalConductivity" -> 0.026, "HeatSource" -> 1|>;
\[CapitalOmega] = Line[{{0}, {1}}];

eqn = HeatTransferPDEComponent[vars, pars] == 0

Tfun = NDSolveValue[{eqn, 
    HeatTemperatureCondition[x == 0, vars, 
     pars, <|"SurfaceTemperature" -> 0|>]}, \[CapitalTheta], 
   x \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]];
Plot[Tfun[x], {x} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]
```

I want to add that I am new to Mathematica. Further I tried running some code snippets not using the HeatTransferPDEComponent stuff but defining the heat equation in the code, which worked just fine.

Comment: Indeed, I can't activate `HeatTransferPDEComponent[{\[CapitalTheta][t, x], t, {x}}, <|
  "MassDensity" -> \[Rho], "SpecificHeatCapacity" -> Subscript[C, p], 
  "ThermalConductivity" -> \[Kappa]|>]` in 12.3.

Comment: I am running 12.1 by the way.

Comment: @user64494, works just fine for me on 12.3

Comment: @user21: I obtain "Div::sclr: The scalar expression (-\[Kappa]).{(\[CapitalTheta]^(0,1))[t,x]} does not have a divergence."

Comment: @user64494, what OS?

Comment: @user21: Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: @user64494, now I get it. This is expected if want to active the PDE you need to use: `HeatTransferPDEComponent[{\[CapitalTheta][t, x], t, {x}}, <|
   "MassDensity" -> \[Rho], "SpecificHeatCapacity" -> Subscript[C, p],
    "ThermalConductivity" -> {{\[Kappa]}}|>] // Activate` Note the {{k}}. I probably should add this as a possible issues entry and / or not use k without the braces.

Comment: @user64494, I have added this caveat to the Possible Issue section of `HeatTransferPDEComponent` and removed the usage of the symbolic kappa without proper matrix braces. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HeatTransferPDEComponent` was introduced in version 12.2 so will need at least that version to run it. See how the function name is still blue - this means that symbol is not defined in the version you run.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was going crazy on not being able to run the tutorial cases.

Comment: @Tobias, but there is a heat transfer tutorial in 12.1, it just does not make use of the newly added functions. You could have a look at that. There are, of course, no reference pages in 12.1 as then the functions did not exist. But maybe this is an incentive to get the update.

Comment: I can't update unfortunately as I am adding to some existing code that requires some older stuff.
Any chance you know where I can find those old tutorials? I've been googling for quite a while and couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Paste `PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer` into the help system